# Hive count(*) query is not invoking mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have external tables in hive, I am trying to run **select count(*) from table_name** query but the query returns instantaneously and gives result which is i think already stored. The result returned by query is not correct. Is there a way to force a map reduce job and make the query execute each time.

Note: This behavior is not followed for all external tables but some of them.

Versions used : Hive 0.14.0.2.2.6.0-2800, Hadoop 2.6.0.2.2.6.0-2800 (Hortonworks)

Comment: For Hive to do a count(*) , there is no need for a MR job. Could you provide more details to prove the results are wrong?

Comment: I am doing row count (wc -l) for checking the number of rows and my data format is orc so is this the right method to check ?

Answer (score 2):

After some finding I have got a method that kicks off MR for counting number of records on orc table.

ANALYZE TABLE *'table name'* PARTITION(*'partition columns'*) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
--OR
ANALYZE TABLE *'table name'* COMPUTE STATISTICS;

This is not a direct alternative for count(*) but provides latest count of records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `wc -l` on ORC data won't give you an accurate result, since the data is encoded. This would work if the data was stored in a simple text file format with one row per line.

Hive does not need to launch a MapReduce for count(*) of an ORC file since it can use the ORC metadata to determine the total count.

Use the `orcfiledump` command to analyse ORC data from the command line

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, COUNT(*) on an ORC table usually returns **wrong** figures -- i.e. it returns the number of rows on the *first* data file only. If the table was fed by multiple INSERTs then you are stuck.

With V0.13 you could fool the optimizer into running a dummy M/R job by adding a dummy "where 1=1" clause -- takes much longer, but actually counts the rows.

With 0.14 the optimizer got smarter, you must add a non-deterministic clause e.g. "where MYKEY is null". Assuming that MYKEY is a String, otherwise the "is null" clause may crash your query -- another ugly ORC bug.

By the way, a SELECT DISTINCT on partition key(s) will also return wrong results -- all existing partitions will be shown, even the empty ones. Not specific to ORC this time.

Answer (score 0):

please try the below :

**hive>set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none** in your hive session and then trigger select count(*) operation in your hive session to mandate mapreduce